# Internet explorer: inconsistent background color on selection

Tags: css, internet-explorer, selection, pseudo-element

On selection of text, background color of text usually changes to blue. but in my application it is changing to white with blue foreground. This is happening when I set foreground to `#FE4A49` and only on IE (I'm using *11.0.9600.18763*). I've not set any CSS rules for `::selection` Pseudo-element.

Can somebody help me understanding, Why this is happening ? And what is best way to handle it?

```
Here is my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/g8tgmgsy/3/
```

[image]

Comment: In the fiddle, both lines get the same light blue on white when I select them. Same version of IE (11.0.9600.18763).